# How to make ruby methods run before and after each [given, when, then] step?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

I'm trying to get some easy-to-read time metrics for how long steps of each scenario take to run.

I have methods that insert rows into a logging table like this:

`puts "#{Time.now} - Starting Given"`

`puts "#{Time.now} - Ending Given"`

`etc...`

And I want them to be called automatically at the start and end of each step, but I can only find ways to run them before or after the **entire scenario**, rather than each step.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby comes with a [benchmarking module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to handle this stuff pretty easily for you.

**Edit to address the comments below**

In Cucumber, there is a hook called `Around` that allows you to wrap your scenario however you wish. For example, straight from the docs:

```
Around('@fast') do |scenario, block|
  Timeout.timeout(0.5) do
    block.call #actually runs the scenario
  end
end
```

Comment: This sounds very cool, but the issue really isn't with figuring out the benchmarking, but with just getting (any kind of of) specific ruby code to run before and after each step.

Something like this is what I need (formatting is borked, so pasting here: https://paste.ee/p/J3pPG )

Comment: Ah, it seemed like you were just looking for a way to benchmark easily. If you need to actually run code before/after like you describe, it looks like you need to write a `before` method yourself.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way within hooks.rb to specify this?

I know I can do this with tags, but again, this works on a scenario level, rather than a step level.

Comment: Is `Around` not what you are looking to do? Didn't realize until just now that this was about cucumber.

Comment: I will look into this right now, thanks for the tip.

Comment: So, the around hook is still scenario based, but I believe I found the same website you were looking at, and saw there is an AfterStep hook.

I just tried it out, and it does basically what I want.